# Present numeric values with two digits in Python 3.5 / Ipython 7.3.0

Tags: python

How can I present a numeric value by its first two digits in Python? In addition to the first two digits requested, one or more zeros should appear as placeholders for numbers greater or equal to 100.
The Mathematica code looks like this:

```
pf2[val_] := PaddedForm[N@val, 2]

pf2[12.345]
12

pf2@12345
12000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format` for this:

```
>>> "{:.2g}".format(12.345)
'12'
>>> "{:.2g}".format(12345)
'1.2e+04'
```

If the result should be a `float`, use:

```
>>> float("{:.2g}".format(12.345))
12.0
>>> float("{:.2g}".format(12345))
12000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `round` function accepts negative values to allow for rounding to the nearest 10, 100, etc. We can use `log10` for determining how much to round by:

```
from math import log10, floor

def significant_digits(num, sig_digits):
  return round(num, -int(floor(log10(abs(num))) - (sig_digits - 1)))


# Trying it out
print(significant_digits(12345, 1))  # 10000
print(significant_digits(12345, 2))  # 12000
print(significant_digits(12345, 3))  # 12300
print(significant_digits(12543, 2))  # 13000
print(significant_digits(1.2567, 2)) # 1.3
print(significant_digits(0.2345, 2)) # 0.23
```